# C# thread array

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a problem with array of threads in C#. When I start threads if for loop and send in parameter some threads get same value.

```
Thread[] nit = new Thread[n];

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    nit[i] = new Thread(() => functionThread(i + 1)); //functionThread => thread
    nit[i].IsBackground = true;
    nit[i].Name = string.Format("Thread: {0}", i + 1);
    nit[i].Start();
    Thread.Sleep(500); //I have problem here
}

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    nit[i].Join();
}
```

If n = 4 the values in threads should be 1, 2, 3, 4. But if i remove "Thread.Sleep(500);" or i set value less than 500 the values become for example 2, 2, 3, 4.

How could I make this work without Thread.Sleep() and still have correct values in threads?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
int iLocal = i;
nit[i] = new Thread(() => functionThread(iLocal + 1)); //functionThread => thread
```

It happens because you are passing a variable, instead of the value. This is similiar problem: [Captured variable in a loop in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/captured-variable-in-a-loop-in-c-sharp)

You can learn more about closures from Jon's post: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure "It happens because you are passing a variable, instead of the value. " is really an accurate explanation of why this is happening. It has to do with the timing of when the captured `i` is accessed in `functionThread` - whether it's before the loop increments it or after.

Comment: @lc. And the reason that the timing is relevant is because the closure closes over the *variable*, not the *value*.  Had the closure closed over the *value* that timing wouldn't have been relevant.

Comment: @Servy Ahh, now I understand what that sentence was getting at. Sorry, it just didn't make sense to me the first three times I read it (time for bed?). Thanks for the clarification.